# Class in App_Code not accessible by Global.asax.cs

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, app-code

I've created a new class in App_Code

```
namespace Site {
    public class MyClass {
        public MyClass() {
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Global.asax.cs

```
namespace Site {
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            *MyClass myClass = new MyClass();*
        }
    }
}
```

The error is in: *MyClass myClass = new MyClass();*

The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have other classes inside App_Code.  I've tried pasting MyClass into one of those class and Global.asax.cs can find MyClass.  Weird.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally found out what went wrong.  I've set the Build Action of the cs file to **Content** instead of **Compile**